# Where's the flaw in this construction of a set that's both countable and uncountable?

Tags: logic, set-theory, paradoxes

Say we constructed a set of all finite math expressions, which is countable. Then we take the subset of expressions that evaluate to a single real number. That subset should still be countable. Now we apply the Cantor argument to this subset to construct a new real number. I'm assuming all of this can probably be done using a finite expression, so this number should've been in the subset already.

So the subset is both countable and uncountable at the same time. Where's the flaw in this logic? Are there multiple?

Comment: How you perform step 3:  Now we apply the Cantor argument to this subset to construct a new real number ?

Comment: This is all very vague.  I;m not sure what construction you have in mind, but whatever real number you produced, you'd have to demonstrate that it was the output of a "finite math expression."

Comment: I'm not completely convinced that the set of all finite math expressions *is* countable. Can you make sure you've proved that?

Comment: what is a math expression? What is a finite math expression? Why would such set be countable?

Comment: re Mauro ALLEGRANZA - I assumed the subset is countable, and you just construct a real number that's 0 in the i-th position position after the decimal point, if the i-th number in the subset has 1..9 in that position, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: But no one was disputing that the set of real numbers is uncountable, so the fact that you can make a new real number, given a countable list of them, is no surprise.

Comment: The gap is in "I'm **assuming** all of this can **probably** be done using a finite expression"

Comment: What do you mean by "finite math expressions"? If they contain real numbers, there cannot be countable number of such expressions. If they contain rational numbers only, it is doubtful that you'll be able to construct any real number.

Comment: You're basically running into [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem): for any appropriate framework of "expressions" and "evaluations," performing the process you describe is not actually definable within the original framework - it takes a *slightly more expressive* framework to do the job. So there's no contradiction at the end of the argument. (I've put this as a comment rather than an answer since I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question.)

Comment: This is essentially Richard's paradox, and the "solution" (as Noah points out with Tarski's undefinability) is basically just that there isn't really a finite expression that decides when another finite expression defines a unique real in the wider world.  For example, "$x=0$ and CH holds" would define nothing if CH were false, but if it were true, then this expression would uniquely define a real: $0$.  To say whether an expression defines something, we therefore need access to truth which, again as Noah points out, isn't something we can access with a single formula.

Answer (score 3):

*I keep finding near-duplicates but can't find an exact duplicate, so here goes:*

---

Note that you haven't  been clear about what "finite expression" means. This is in fact the problem that turns into the fundamental error:

> "I'm assuming all of this can probably be done using a finite expression."

Your whole argument hinges on the claim that the "antidiagonal real" corresponding to whatever system of definitions you're using is definable *by a definition within that system itself*. This may feel obvious, especially since we're generally not very careful about the precise nature of mathematical language. However, it is in fact **false**: a [general theorem of Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), usually stated for first-order logic but much more broadly applicable than that, says that this is in fact almost never the case!

---

I think the main obstacle to understanding this is the fact that we generally only have one "mathematical language" in mind, namely the *informal-but-"rigorous"* natural language we actually use to talk about mathematics. To de-mystify things a bit, consider "local" versions of Cantor's theorem: given a "complexity class" (in a very broad sense) $\mathfrak{C}$ we can talk about $(i)$ reals definable by an expression in $\mathfrak{C}$ and $(ii)$ arrays definable by an expression in $\mathfrak{C}$. The process of forming the antidiagonal corresponding to a given array is simple enough that, for "reasonable" $\mathfrak{C}$, it's something $\mathfrak{C}$ lets us do. The "local Cantor's theorem," then, is this:

> The $\mathfrak{C}$-definable reals can never be put into a single $\mathfrak{C}$-definable array. Put another way, the set of $\mathfrak{C}$-definable reals is not "$\mathfrak{C}$-countable.

For example:

- The *polynomial-time-computable* reals, while obviously countable, are not *polynomial-time-computably* countable.
- The *computable* reals, while obviously countable, are not *computably* countable.
- The reals which are *first-order definable over $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ without parameters*, while obviously countable, are not *$(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$-definably-without-parameters* countable.

And so on. In my opinion this "local" analysis will, once understood, clear up a lot of the issues one may have with both Cantor's argument *and* general ideas about definability broadly construed. *(That's not to say that everything about definability and countability suddenly becomes intuitive - see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) for an example which trips plenty of people up! - but it's a good first step.)*

Comment: Incidentally, since it's not the big issue I've tacitly accepted that "systems of definitions" are inherently countable. But depending who you talk to this isn't always true. For example, I personally consider [infinitary logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/) to provide perfectly valid systems of definitions, even though they're very far from countable.

Comment: Quite an unsavory truth, but thank You.

Comment: @IngusPRET That's a matter of taste. Personally I'm quite pleased by the situation - the subtlety of definability is what makes mathematical logic so exciting!

Comment: @IngusPRET Has this answered your question?

Comment: Yes, I think I see where the problems are.